# Loading data into webpage which requires multiple calls to API

Tags: javascript, api

For my website I am using an API where I need to load several variables from. Each of the variables are dependent on the return value of the previous call (I use the returned variable from call 1 to make call 2 etc).

Example:
Say that I need to make 5 different API calls to gather all of my data and each is dependent on the return value of the previous call. Then in my case I am doing like this. I am passing a callback function to the first function that loads the data. Then that function will make the first API call. When that call is finished it will pass the callback function to the next function that makes the second API call, and so on. When the last API call is finished the callback function gets called and then I know that all the data has been loaded. In code it would look something like this (I am using the Trello API in my application so I will use it in the example below):

```
function loadData(cb){
  //Make the first API call
  Trello.get('/member/me/boards', function(boards){
    myBoards = boards;
    for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
      //Make the second API call
      Trello.get('/boards/' + board[i].id + '/lists', function(lists){
        board[i].lists = lists;
        //Then make the third and fourth and so on 
        .....
        //When all calls are made call the callback function
        cb();
      });
  });
}
```

As you can see the callback function will be passed a long way into the callstack. I was wondering if there is a better way to load the data and to store it (as of now I just store everything in a large array). And what is some best practices for loading large amount of data from an API?

P.S. In my original code each of the API calls are in separate functions, but I simplified it here to reduce the amount of code in the example.

Comment: Async calls in a sync loop are always a bad idea. May iterate your tree recursively... And might it be better to show the data in chunks, so the user mustnt wait that long?

Comment: I need all data to be loaded before I can show it. But I understand what you meant with making async calls in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an option for you but using **TypeScript** makes solving this kind of JavaScript problem much more simple:

```
async function loadData() {
    const boards = await Trello.get('/member/me/boards');
    return boards.map(async (board) => {
        const lists = await Trello.get('/boards/' + board.id + '/lists');
        const something = await Trello.get('/...');
        const somethingElse = await Trello.get('/...');
        // ...more calls
        return {
            ...board,
            lists: lists,
            something: something,
            somethingElse: somethingElse
            // ... more attributes
        };
    });
}

loadData().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: The code I wrote uses async / await and object spread which are features available in TypeScript (soon to become available in JavaScript as well). I didn't use types because they are optional.

Comment: That was something like what I had in mind. It would make the code much more readable and easier to add a variable if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding your problem this may not be a valid solution, but taking a quick glance at the [trello api docs](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/batch) shows a batch call you could make to avoid looping at each level. Batching these would allow for many fewer API calls at each level and would be considered a best practice:

```
function loadData(cb){
  //Make the first API call
  Trello.get('/member/me/boards', function(boards){
    myBoards = boards;
    var boardAPIs = [];
    var boardResponses = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
      boardAPIs.push('/boards/' + board[i].id + '/lists');
      //max of 10 at a time per documentation
      if (boardAPIs.length == 10 || i >= (boards.length - 1)) {
          //Make the second level API call
         Trello.get('/batch/?urls=' + boardAPIs.join(','), function(boards){
            // collect response information on all boards, then continue with third request
            boardResponses.push(...);

            if (i >= (boards.length - 1)) {
                // all board requests have been made, continue execution at third level
                // if this were the last level of calls, you could call cb() here
                for(var j = 0; i < boardResponses.length; i++){
                    // loop inside responses to get individual board responses, build up next set of batch requests
                }
            }
         });
         boardAPIs= [];
      }
     });


  });
}
```

One thing to note here: the docs mentioned that you can only batch 10 requests at a time, so I added some code in there to check for that.

[This post](https://blog.clarkrasmussen.com/2014/10/13/batch-requests-with-the-trello-api/) provides more information on how to consume the batch service:

> this means you get only a single response back, and it looks a little
>   different from a normal response.  The response is an array of objects
>   – but not of the normal response objects you might expect.  Instead,
>   it’s an object with a single property, with a name set to the HTTP
>   response code of the request.

Comment: Thank you for that. I never noticed the batch service in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You may focus on a *deep first* approach, so that the first data arrives fast at the client:

```
function loadData(showChunk){
//Make the first API call
Trello.get('/member/me/boards', function(boards){
   myBoards = boards;
   (function getboard(i){
        //Make the second API call
        Trello.get('/boards/' + board[i].id + '/lists', function(lists){
             board[i].lists = lists;
        //Then make the third and fourth and so on 
        .....
        //When all calls are made for the first board call the callback function, and also continue with the next board
        showChunk();
        if(i+1<boards.length) setTimeout(getboard, 1, i+1);
     });
    })(0);
 });
}
```